# Matlab: Delete the item in an N-dimensional array whose Nth dimension is 1, where N is unknown?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an N-dimensional array of items whose last dimension is the index of the array.

For example, if the array A contained images, then A(:,:,:,1) would be the first image, A(:,:,:,2) would be the second image, and so forth.

Similarly, if the array just contained integers, then A(:,1) would be the first integer, A(:,2) would be the second integer, and so forth.

-=-=-=-

What I'm trying to do is delete the first item from A when I do not know ahead of time what dimensionality it is.

If A contains images, I want to do this:

```
A(:,:,:,1) = [];
```

If A contains integers, I want to do this:

```
A(:,1) = [];
```

The problem is since I don't know what dimensionality it is, I don't know how many colons to put, and I don't know how to denote "N-1 colons here" in Matlab.

I'm hoping there is a programmatic way to do this, but I frankly have no idea what to search for if this is possible.

Comment: For the number of dimensions, try using `length(size(A))` or `ndims(A)`. I'm not sure how to do the "select all from the first n-1 dimensions" thing yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use cell to comma-separated list expansion:

```
%// Build cell: {':', ':', ..., ':', [1]}
I(1:ndims(A)-1) = {':'};
I{ndims(A)} = 1;
%// Expand cell to comma separated list and delete:
A(I{:}) = [];
```

Or convert to cell using `num2cell` and then convert back using `cell2mat`:

```
C = num2cell(A,1:ndims(A)-1);
A = cell2mat(C(2:end));
```

I guess that unless you really need n-dimensional arrays, doing this with a cell array of `n-1` dimensional arrays instead (as is `C` in the above code) should be a smart move in terms of simplicity of notation.

Comment: The comma-separated list expansion worked beautifully, many many thanks!